# How to add a new user via the API to OroCRM

Tags: orocrm

Currently, I have a website and I'd like to sync all my users to OroCRM via the API to OroCRM.

Please help me! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can check Oro\Bundle\UserBundle\Tests\Functional\API\RestUsersTest for the request sample

Comment: Hi ishakuta I think You know how to deal with orocrm I also need to  pull some data from magento without using magento extension How can i do that? Please help me the way i should do this?

Comment: You can't because it limited by Magento SOAP API module. If you want to migrate additional data from Magento you have to change API of Magento. OroCRM automatically grab that data and fill Magento customer attributes.

Comment: Hi ishakuta, My Magento Version 1.9.2.3, i have installed Bitnami OroCRM in Windows. After successfully installed then i going to Sync. The Sync is not complete i am getting an error like, Jobs Failed  1) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  2)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  3)  orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1  4) oro_integration:sync_integration:1  5) orocrm_magento:sync_initial_integration:1 all the Jobs Failed. My status error : https://justpaste.it/4rkcs  and log error : https://justpaste.it/61uta How can i solve the issue?